# Can Uncrustify be prevented from modifying certain sections of code?

Tags: c, code-formatting, uncrustify

Uncrustify is great, and does an excellent job of tidying code.
However, I have some C code within a file that I don't want Uncrustify to change. Is there any way I can prevent Uncrustify from touching this, maybe by putting specific tags in comments around the code or something?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
int i = 0; // No uncrustify action here
/* *INDENT-ON* */
```