# Comments that control uncrustify behaviour

Tags: uncrustify

In [this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097501/can-uncrustify-be-prevented-from-modifying-certain-sections-of-code)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097501/can-uncrustify-be-prevented-from-modifying-certain-sections-of-code) i learned that i can use `*INDENT-OFF*` to exclude uncrustify action on certain parts of code.

Unfortunately i was not able to find this information anywhere else.

Does anybody know where i can look this up? Are there other comments which control uncrustifiy behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The `*INDENT-ON*` and `*INDENT-OFF*` are defined in the `uncrustify_types.h` file in the [source code](https://github.com/uncrustify/uncrustify/blob/master/src/uncrustify_types.h)

See also Ben Gardner's comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/uncrustify/bugs/343/#0394